# Refetch Query after mutation success in Apollo GraphQL Client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

If I have two functons, first one is getting documents and second one is removing documents. **All I want to is updating cache after deleting documents success**

The functions are below.

```
const [loadDocuments] = useLazyQuery(GET_PRODUCTS, {
  onCompleted({ getProducts: data }) {
     setRows(data)
  },
  variables: getVariables(),
})

const [loadDelete] = useMutation(REMOVE_PRODUCTS, {
  update(cache, data) {
    // ...
  },
  variables: { ids: selected.join(',') },
})
```

I tried.

**1. Call loadDocuments() after Mutation Success.**

```
const [loadDelete] = useMutation(REMOVE_PRODUCTS, {
  update(cache, data) {
     loadDocuments()
  },
})
```

===> `loadDocuments` does not fired. I don't know why, it doesn't fired.

**2. Add refetchQueries to Delete Mutation**

```
const [loadDelete] = useMutation(REMOVE_PRODUCTS, {
  update(cache, data) {
    // ...
  },
  variables: { ids: selected.join(',') },
  refetchQueries: () => [
    {
      query: GET_PRODUCTS,
      variables: getVariables(),
    },
  ],
})
```

===> It fire query `GET_PRODUCTS`, and perhaps server response something. But I don't know where to catch it to update state.

---

I read some articles that update cache after mutation. They use `readQuery` and `writeQuery`. But In my case, I want to more easy way. If there is table, and table should display 20 rows per page. And then if I delete 2 rows, and I delete 2 rows's cache data, only 18 items left.

Anyway I have to fetch 2 more items. So I think even if I use `readQuery` and `writeQuery`, I should fetch again for 2 rows. So I just want to fetch latest data once. Then it feels more simple. In this situation, what is best practice and is there no way to make it simple?

Comment: `useLazyQuery` returns some refetch fn you can just call use in `update` - see docs/API

Comment: @xdam How do `useLazyQuey` know it is refetched from other function? Of course gql is same

Comment: hook returns a special fn (beside 'standard' `data`, `loading` and `error`) for this purpose

Comment: @xdam I tried   update(cache, data) {
            refetch({ query: GET_PRODUCTS, variables: getVariables() }).then(({ data }) => {console.log(data.getProducts)})},

Comment: @xadm But the console data is not latest data, how can I get latest data? Could you give me some more hints?

Comment: The server response data is latest, But the client console's data is previous one. I don't know why

Comment: @xdam It looks I solved the issue, I should have set refetch functions variable empty, and I added awaitRefetchQueires to useLazyQuery!